# What is wrong with particular solution of $y''+2y'+y=xe^{-x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got:

$$y''+2y'+y=xe^{-x}$$

have found $$y(x) =C_1e^{-x} + C_1xe^{-x}$$

Tried to fund the particular solution as $$y = (Ax+B)xe^{-x}$$

but I always

get $A = -\frac{1}{2}$ while for example WA indecates $\frac{1}{6}$, I've seen the topic about the same equation here with almosth the same problem, but I can not follow the answer there, so I wanr ro ask what exactly wrong here, maybe the pattern of the particular solution?

Comment: Did you try the ansatz $y=(Ax+B)x^2e^{-x}$?

Comment: Using $(Ax+B)xe^{-x}$ is simply wrong - if you do that you shouldn't get $A=-1/2$, you should get $0=1$. Look up the rules for "undetermined coefficients" in the book - it should be $(Ax+B)x^2e^{-x}$.

Comment: try $$y_p=Ax^3e^{-x}$$ i think this will help you

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That indeed works in this case, but do you have a good argument that one should not have a term $Bx^2e^{-x}$, without doing the calculations?

Comment: this was Trial and error by me and i saw your problem

Comment: and i have a very good book about differential equations Kamke, differential equation, there is also a Collection of solved Problem by the same author

Comment: @mickep well, it seems if we have a resonance roots and repearing riits at the same time, multiplying the particular solution with just $x$ is not enough, and we have to multyply it with $x^2$

Comment: That is what I suggested in my first comment. Doing the calculations it turns out that $B=0$ in this case though. I asked @Dr.SonnhardGraubner if he had a good argument why it was like that...

Comment: mickep is correct, we still need a $B$ term in the ansatz for completeness. It just turns out to be $0$ here out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer becomes obvious when you expand

$$(Ax+B)xe^{-x} = Ax^2e^{-x} + Bxe^{-x} $$

You can see the second term is extraneous, as it's already part of the homogeneous. You're left with only one coefficient which isn't sufficient for the polynomial part of $xe^{-x}$. To amend this, we try

$$ y_p = (Ax+B)x^2e^{-x} $$

It should be noted that the power of $x^n$ in the particular form needs to be as least as large as the multiplicity of the homogeneous root, which in this case is $x^2$ for the double root.

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the characteristic root using an exponential factor, here shift it to zero using
$$
(e^xy(x))''=e^x(y''(x)+2y'(x)+y(x))=x.
$$
After integrating twice
$$
e^xy(x)=\frac16x^3+Ax+B.
$$